# Angular 2 production bundle file is too large

Tags: angular, bundle

i use webpack bundle my angular 2 project, when i bundle the main file. the file is too large, the file size is about 8M. then whenever i refresh my page, there will be a long time for the browser to load and execute the javascript files. 
I think there may be too many files that i don't needs,but how can i find it and kick it out of my bundle files? 
thank u for give me some advice or some help.

here is my main part of webpack config:
webpack.common.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;

module.exports = {
    baseUrl: './',
    entry: {
        // 'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        // 'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'main': './src/main.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],
        root: helpers.root('src'),
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
                exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['raw-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader',
                exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
                loader: 'file'
            },
            {
                test: /.(png|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            }
        ]

    },
    plugins: [
        new ForkCheckerPlugin(),
        // new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        //     {from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets'},
        //     {from: 'src/app/i18n', to: 'app/i18n'},
        //     {from: 'src/loading.css', to: 'loading.css'},
        //     {from: 'src/fonts', to: 'fonts'},
        //     {from: 'src/favicon.ico', to: ''},
        //     {from: 'src/img', to: 'img'}]),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
            chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
        })
    ],

    node: {
        global: 'window',
        crypto: 'empty',
        process: true,
        module: false,
        clearImmediate: false,
        setImmediate: false
    }

};
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge'); // used to merge webpack configs
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js'); // the settings that are common to prod and dev
/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const IgnorePlugin = require('webpack/lib/IgnorePlugin');
const DedupePlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/DedupePlugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
        // new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // 如果出现任何错误 就终止构建
        // new DedupePlugin(), // 检测完全相同(以及几乎完全相同)的文件 并把它们从输出中移除
        // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        //     name: ['polyfills', 'vendor', 'main'].reverse()
        // }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            beautify: false,
            mangle: { screw_ie8 : true, keep_fnames: true },
            compress: { screw_ie8: true, warnings: false },
            comments: false
        }),
        // new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'), // 把内嵌的 css 抽取成玩不文件 并为其文件名添加 hash 后缀 使得浏览端缓存失效
        new DefinePlugin({ // 定义环境变量
            'process.env': {
                ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
            }
        }),
    ],

    htmlLoader: {
        minimize: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: false,
        caseSensitive: true,
        customAttrSurround: [
            [/#/, /(?:)/],
            [/\*/, /(?:)/],
            [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/]
        ],
        customAttrAssign: [/\)?\]?=/]
    },

    tslint: {
        emitErrors: true,
        failOnHint: true,
        resourcePath: 'src'
    },

    node: {
        global: 'window',
        crypto: 'empty',
        process: false,
        module: false,
        clearImmediate: false,
        setImmediate: false
    }

});
```

i dropped my vendor.ts file
here is my polyfills.ts

```
// This file includes polyfills needed by Angular 2 and is loaded before
// the app. You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
// Added parts of es6 which are necessary for your project or your browser support requirements.
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-set';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was trying out angular 2 the other day and I faced the same issue as you do, my vendor.js was 6M and this was a simple "Hello World" app...

I've found the following post that helped a lot in understanding how we should act on this issue (for now):
http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/

He uses several optimizing and compression techniques (precompile,treeshake, minify, bundle and gzip) on his 1.5M app to reduce its size to just 50kb.

Check it out, hope it helps! :)

**EDIT:**
I've had a few runs with Angular since, and for me the best working approach was to use the angular-cli, which is at v1.0 when I'm writing this and when you run the build with --prod it does everything I wrote in my original post +a usual web server gzips your files. My complete site is under 1MB with this and his has a lot of functionality and also plenty third party stuff as well.

Comment: I recently used the gzip and got my files to 330kb but I'm having trouble using the app.js.gz file that it created. It seems the browser doesnt like it. I made a question for this, could you take a look please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047617/angular2-gzip-issue-when-i-run-my-app

Comment: I run ng builf --prod and gzip files are created but they aren't used by the index.html file. I'm using angular-cli. Any idea why it's still using the full-sized files?

Comment: I just tried it, to me it doesnt create gzipped files, and this is the right mechanism. Your web server should be gzipping the files on the go. On most of the web servers this is the default setting.

Answer (score -3):

angular 2 support lazyLoad route component ; you can use 
[angular2-router-loader](https://github.com/icepoint0/angular2-router-loader)

or you can use webpack split config;

and you can also use ato / uglify to zip your code;

wish this answer can help u.

Comment: You answer is for XmlHttpRequest-based linking, the question is for the static solutions. You don't answer the question.