# Angular2 GZIP issue when I run my app

Tags: javascript, angular, gzip, systemjs, cloudflare

I have an angular2 typescript app.

I host with Firebase and use cloudflare for speed, caching and protection.

The browser header says: accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br

This gets converted to a app.js file and is minified now to 1.6mb.

**I then GZIP Compressed this app.js file.**

I'm wanting to use the app.js file that is now GZIP compressed rather than the original 1.6mb app.js file. Therefore, I point to the **app.js.gz file** in my index.html page and I get a browser error called:

**app.js.gz:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

Below is a screen grabs of my app.js file and index.html.

[image]

Let me know if you request any more info or screen grabs.

It seems like I need to do something else in order for it to work.
Do I need to do some cloudflare settings to accept a .gz file or something?

Comment: You don't have to include app.js.gzip file, just include it normally, app.js , serve will request gzipped version on the fly.

Comment: Yeh but it's too slow the app when I do that e.g. Four seconds

Comment: I didn't mean that. what i was saying if your server is configured properly it will pick gzipped version automatically, you don't need to include gzipped version.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803472/what-is-bundle-js-gz-file-in-angular-2/39804016?noredirect=1#comment69303161_39804016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those gzips are meat for webservers that can use pregzipped files that they dont have to gzip it with every request or cache it.
The js it then transfered compressed and the browser/cloudflare handles the rest. So you dont have to edit the script tags to use gzip or dont use it.

But you can simply use nginx and enable gzip there (and dont use the .gz) for the few request from cloudflare.

Comment: I looked at the lazy loading and it seems simple. Can it be fussy to run? And will it reduce my apps 4 second load time

Comment: It depends, you will have smaller "submodules", but you cannot import directly between without ruining benefits, but it will make the start of the app faster and smaller if you dont need all code for the route, but the code required for another route will be loaded later and the page will not appear instantly.

Comment: So ideally il lazy load my admin pages and pages deep in the site ?

Comment: I think loading admin pages separately has only benefits, because a normal user will never visit them. Then you can for example bundle all pages where the user is logged in, because they often will already share some oth the code and `CanActivate`. I would simply look what other pages bring benefits, or if each page is "specialized" maybe trying to use it for every page

Comment: Thanks Julian I will try tonight and let you know how I get on

Comment: Hi julian, I gave lazy loading an attempt and came across some issues getting it to work. I read that blog and tried implementing the information. I've made a new question for this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067311/angular2-lazy-loading-a-route-issue