# Angular2 lazy loading a route issue

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular2-routing, systemjs

Angular2 lazy loading a route issue.

I'm using Angular2, typscript, html5 and systemjs.

I'm trying to get lazy loading working for one of my basic routes.
This is the blog I'm following but I can't seem to get it working: http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-ngmodule/

**This is the console error I get:**

Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '500'

My page is the 500 page. 
Below I have added my files at there current state.

**Module for 500 page:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Component500 } from './500.component';
import { ModuleRouting500 } from './500.routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule, ModuleRouting500],
  declarations: [Component500],
  exports: [Component500],
  providers: []
})
export default class Module500 { }
```

**Route for 500 page:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Component500 } from './index';

const Routes500: Routes[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: Component500
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(Routes500)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})

export class ModuleRouting500 { }
```

**This is my core app routes page: (I don't add the route 500 here)**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeRoutes } from './components/home/index';

export const routes: Routes = [
...HomeRoutes,
```

{ path: '500', loadChildren: 'app/components/500/500.module#Module500' }
    ];

**This is my core app module page: (I don't add the module 500 here)**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeModule } from './components/home/home.module';
import { AuthService } from './services/authService/authService';
import { Environment } from './models/environment/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, CommonModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), 
  HomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'},
    AuthService,
    Environment
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**This is the 500 page index.ts file:**

```
export * from './500.component';
export * from './500.routes';
```

**This is a screen grab of my folder structure:**

[image]

**This is a screen grab of my console error I currently get:**

[image]

**Full folder structure:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your lazy route in the App route by doing this:

App routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    ...,
    { path: '500', loadChildren: 'app/components/500/500.module#Module500' },
];
```

You have to change your 500.routes.ts to a module like:

500.routes.ts:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Component500 } from './index';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: Component500,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(Routes500)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Then, in 500.module.ts you have to load the 500.routes.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Component500 } from './500.component';
import { routing  } from './500.routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule, routing],
  declarations: [Component500]
})
export class Module500 { }
```

Now, every module knows the routes, being it lazy or not.